# How to emit inputs on change using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I'm working on a chat style app using React and socket.io, and I want to implement something where a client can see the input being typed by the other client in realtime. I'm using `onChange` on the input to update the state and emit the message at the same time, but that only sends messages one letter at a time to the server, and deletions don't work at all.

Here's the frontend with extra code omitted:

```
this.state = {
        text: '',
        name: '',
        messages: []
    }
componentDidMount() {
    socket.on('RECIEVE_MESSAGE', function(msg) {
        this.setState({
            messages: [...this.state.messages, msg]
        })
    })
}
onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        text: event.target.value
})
    socket.emit('example_message', this.state.text);
    this.setState({
        messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.text]
    })    
}
return (
        <div>
            <form type="text" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="text-input"
                    id="name-input"
                    name="text-input"
                    required="required"
                    placeholder="text"
                    //used to save end result
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChange={this.onInputChange}></input>
                {/* <button className="next-btn"> NEXT </button> */}
                <button onClick={this.sendSocketIO}>Send Socket.io</button>
            </form>
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            <p>{this.state.messages}. </p>
        </div>
    )
```

And the backend:

```
io.on('connection', client => {
 console.log('Socket connected: ', client.id);
 //recieves the message from the client, and then re-emits to everyone     
client.on('SEND_MESSAGE', data => {
data.message = validate.blacklist(data.message, ['<','>','&','"','/']);
io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data);
});
```

I'd like to render to the DOM a live feed of what the other client is typing, and update it with every character and character deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emitting with:

```
socket.emit('example_message', this.state.text)
```

and handling with:

```
client.on('SEND_MESSAGE', data...
```

Use the same name for the message to emit and then handle on the server.